# Deduct an integer from another integer every time a checkbox is ticked

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I'm currently working on a sheet that has a "Total" stat on it which will represents slots and I want that total slots number to be deducted by "1" every time a tick box is checked.

For example, there are 8 total slots and there are 8 Tick Boxes, each time a slot is consumed, a box is ticked and the total remaining slots is deducted by 1.

What would be the best way of making this happen? I understand I can enable "iterative calculations" and have something like

```
=SUM(F15,IF(F15>0,SUM(IF(K15,-1,0)+IF(L15,-1,0)+IF(M15,-1,0)+IF(N15,-1,0),0)))
```

I'm a total spreadsheet noob but there has to be a more consolidated way to do it.

[Example image of total with tick boxes.][image: 1]

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: @TheMaster I was going to add an example table but figured there wasn't much point given the simplified format is one number and 8 tick boxes. But I've added an image to the original post that shows an example of what I'm working with.

Comment: `=8-sum(C2:F3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=8-SUMPRODUCT(B1:E2)
```

[image]

Comment: As allways the simplest, upped

Comment: Simple and does the job perfectly, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTA(B1:E2)-SUM(IF(B1:E2=TRUE,1,0)))
```

[image]

### Named functions - *why not*

Go to: Data > named functions

Lets name the function DEUCECOUNTA
and paste this in formula definition

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTA(range)-SUM(IF(range=TRUE,1,0)))
```

Paste "**range**" this in the argument place holders and press enter.

**Use it like this**

```
=DEUCECOUNTA(B1:E2)
```

[image]

### Demo

[image]

Comment: I'm using the simpler solution but thank you for this! I now know how to create named functions, which will definitely come in handy in the future.